# File write, without deleting old lines?

Tags: c++, fwrite

I currently have this to write to a file in my program. I have all the variables ready to put into the file I just have an issue.

```
void fileWrite(int score)
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open("MathGen.txt");
    file << "The score was: " << score;
    file.close();
}
```

So when this runs it creates the files and writes the score perfectly fine. But if I re-run the program and get a new score it will overwrite the old score. Is there any way to stop this from happening? I know in python you could use file write functions such as "a+". But that doesn't work here.

Comment: Add `ios::ate` to the flags.

Answer (score 2):

You should use *append* mode on your file in `ofstream.open`:

```
file.open("MathGen.txt", std::ofstream::app);
```

More info on this method is [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/)